# How can I collapse child items in hover sidebar in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have sidebar in my project. When I hover over each sidebar with the mouse, the sidebar opens here, everything is fine, but inside the sidebar I have a collapse dropdown menu. When I open this menu, it opens, but when I move the mouse away from the sidebar and move the mouse over the sidebar again, collapse remains open. You will understand it more clearly in the screenshots.What I want is that the space does not appear between the icons when the sidebar is closed.

Template sidebar

```
<v-navigation-drawer width="320" :disable-resize-watcher="true">
      <v-list v-if="userRole == 'Distributor' || isSuper">
        <v-list-tile
          :append="true"
          v-for="(item, index) in distMenu"
          :key="index"
          :class="{
            'active-sidebar-item': item.href.includes(activeLinkRef),
          }"
          style="margin-bottom: 5px;"
        >
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>
              <router-link :to="item.href">{{
                item.title
              }}</router-link></v-list-tile-title
            >
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
      <v-list v-if="userRole == 'Sysadmin' && !isSuper">
        <v-list-tile
          :append="true"
          v-for="(item, index) in sysMenu"
          :key="index"
          :class="{
            'active-sidebar-item': item.href.includes(activeLinkRef),
          }"
          style="margin-bottom: 5px;"
        >
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>
              <router-link :to="item.href">{{
                item.title
              }}</router-link></v-list-tile-title
            >
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
      <v-list v-if="userRole != 'Distributor' || isSuper">
        <v-list-tile
          :append="true"
          v-for="(item, index) in menu"
          :key="index"
          :class="{
            'active-sidebar-item': item.href.includes(activeLinkRef),
          }"
          style="margin-bottom: 5px;"
        >
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-title>
            <router-link :to="item.href">{{ item.title }}</router-link>
          </v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
        <Facilities
          :facilities="facilities"
          v-if="
            (userRole.toLowerCase() != 'distributor' && hasCompany) ||
              isSuper
          "
          :activeLinkRef="activeLinkRef"
        ></Facilities>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

Facilities.vue

```
  <v-list-group
      prepend-icon="business"
      :value="false"
      v-for="(facility, index) in facilities"
      :key="index"
      :class="{
        'active-sidebar-item':
          activeLinkRef[0] == 'facility' && activeLinkRef[1] == facility.id,
      }"
      style="margin-bottom: 5px"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator>
        <v-list-tile :append="true">
          <router-link :to="'/facility/' + facility.id">{{
            facility.name
          }}</router-link>
        </v-list-tile>
      </template>
      <systems
        :systems="facility.systems.length > 0 ? facility.systems : []"
        :facility="facility.id"
        :activeLinkRef="activeLinkRef"
      ></systems>
    </v-list-group>
    <v-list-tile
      class="input-list-tile"
      v-if="isSuper || userRole.toLowerCase() == 'sysadmin'"
    >
      <v-list-tile-title
        style="padding-left: 54px; height: 40px"
        class="input-option"
      >
        <!-- <input
          style="border: 1px solid #dedede"
          type="text"
          name="add-facility"
          id="add-facility"
          :placeholder="$t('sidebar.addFacility')"
          @keyup.enter="addFacility"
        /> -->
        <b-form-input
          size="sm"
          style="border: 1px solid #dedede"
          class="w-100"
          name="add-facility"
          id="add-facility"
          :placeholder="$t('sidebar.addFacility')"
          @keyup.enter="addFacility"
        ></b-form-input>
      </v-list-tile-title>
      <v-list-tile-action style="justify-content: right;">
        <v-icon @click="addFacility">add</v-icon>
      </v-list-tile-action>
    </v-list-tile>
```

when the mouse is not over the sidebar

[image]

When I open the sidebar, everything is fine so far.

[image]

When I move the mouse away from the sidebar, the sidebar closes and this image appears

[image]

Comment: I dont know much about vue but you can try to add logic so that when the user hovers away and the sidebar is closed, for it to close all the inner collapse menus that are open, either by removing a specific class, or by applying a certain class or a different approach depedning on how you tell your code to open that collapse menu, just try reversing it

Comment: yes i tried that things i tried `visibility: hidden;` This feature just prevents it from appearing, but when the sidebar gets smaller, there is still space between the icons. The other feature I tried is `display:none`, but this removes it completely, sidebar doesn't come back when I hover.

Comment: you can put them on `display: none` and add an eventListener to when the + icon is clicked for it to `display: block`

Comment: can you show it with a code example? I couldn't do it.When the sidebar gets smaller, there is always a space between the icons :(

Comment: check the answer I left you, let me know how it looks from your perspective because I dont undestand much of the code of vue

Comment: i tried but i couldn't.I can't remove the space between the icons somehow

Comment: try inspecting the page and look at what is causing that space.. perhaps there is something getting padding which is causing your issue, maybe its a css issue happening

Answer (score -1):

First your collapse menus to display none.

Create a class, for example:

```
.display-item {
   display: block;
}
```

as for the on click try this Jquery code:

```
$("put the drop down class here").click(function(){
  $("put your tage here").toggleClass("display-item");
});
```